# magento customer group catalog rule error in 1.9.0

Tags: magento-1.9

I did some research and found that there is a bug in my current version of magento 1.9.0.1 that messes up catalog rules for a specific customer group. This bug was fixed in the 1.9.1 release. 
I would like to try and fix this bug without necessarily upgrading. Any tips?

Specifically, the error as I see it will give a discount to my selected customer group in the catalog listing on my site, but when adding to cart, the price without discount is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried setting a group price based on the customer group in the price options for a product, and found that the problem remained the same. The catalog showed the correct discounted price, but when adding to cart it didn't reflect it.

I searched for a solution on that problem and came across this:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4154/group-prices-isnt-getting-added-to-the-cart

and

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/shopping-cart-price-rules-not-applied-to-correct-group-id

It basically suggests disabling the automatic assignment to a customer group based on tax class.

This can be found in system> configuration> customer configuration> create new account options>  Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group.

I set this to "no" and refreshed cache and index, and the prices are now showing correctly in the cart.